# What is the permitted level of lookup in v-if directives?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a piece of markup like this:

```
<div class="form-group" v-if="model.owner.enabled">
```

The model that is available in the scope looks like this:

```
{
   ...
   owner: {
      enabled: true
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

But vue does not like it and goes:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined
```

Can anyone spot the error? Is it maybe because the lookup is limited to the first level of the model object?

As a matter of fact if I change the markup to:

```
<div class="form-group" v-if="model.owner">
```

It just works and the element gets rendered. Supposedly because the `model.owner` object is considered a truthy value I guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no limit. I suspect the issue here is your model is populated asynchronously. If that is the case, then, when the Vue is first rendered, `model.owner` is going to be `undefined` and `model.owner.enabled` will result in the error you described.

`model.owner` probably works because `model` is defined and `owner` isn't when the the Vue is rendered. Then, when the model is populated, `owner` is no longer undefined.

You might handle that by using a guard.

```
<div class="form-group" v-if="model.owner && model.owner.enabled">
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qmmEqb?editors=1010).

Comment: Well spotted mate. It is exactly as you said. So how should I handle the situation?

Comment: @nourdine Use a guard. `v-if="model.owner && model.owner.enabled"`. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qmmEqb?editors=1010

Comment: Lovelly! It woks.